# Angular 4 Jasmine Unit Test Directive Export Function

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have a created custom directive in angular 4 the directive is below.

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALIDATORS, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
export function appValidator(control: FormControl) {
let tWordsLength = false;
if (control.value) {
let test = control.value.split(",");
var lengths = test.map(function (word) {
  if(word.length > 30){
    tWordsLength = true;
  }
  return word.length
})
if (test.length > 10 || tWordsLength) {
  return {
    tagsDomain: {
      parsedDomain: false
    }
  }
}
}
return null;
}
@Directive({
  selector: '[appGeneral][ngModel]',
   providers: [
   {
    provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
    useValue: appValidator,
    multi: true
   }
 ]
})
export class GeneralDirective {
};
```

**And My spec is as below**

```
import {TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { GeneralDirective } from './app-general.directive';
describe('GeneralDirective', () => {
beforeEach(() => {
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   declarations: [GeneralDirective]
  });
 });
 it('should create an instance', () => {
   const directive = new GeneralDirective();
   expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
  });
 });
```

I want to cover the unit testing for export function 'appValidator' in Directive. Can anyone suggest the way on how to achieve coverage on export function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coverage is easy

```
it('should cover the function', () => {
  appValidator(new FormControl(''));
});
```

If this is what you ask. But you should also test if your functions works as desired.

Comment: It gives an error "Cannot find name appValidator" do i need to import any module??

Comment: No problem, if it solves your issue, be sure to mark it as resolved !